# Replay button in flash cs5.5

Tags: flash, button, replay

I have inserted my replay button into my flash movie and it works.

The problem is when I replay my movie some aspects of my animation do not work in the replay.

I believe this is because I have other timelines for movement e.g birds wings.

How do i implement code so that the entire movie will replay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your project is mostly animation and little to no code, you can place all of the animation into a `MovieClip`. Export this symbol for ActionScript, giving it the class name `Animation`.

Your replay button could simply remove the current instance of your animation and then re-attach it (which should reset the entire content).

Sample:

```
var animation:Animation;

replay.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK _replay);
function _replay(e:MouseEvent = null):void
{
    if(animation != null)

        if(animation.parent)
            animation.parent.removeChild(animation);
    }

    animation = new Animation();

    addChild(animation);
}

_replay();
```